# ZF2 PHP5.5 Cache Storage alternative for APC

Tags: php, zend-framework2, apc, opcache

I have been using ZF2 with PHP 5.3 and APC cache, and now I upgraded to PHP 5.5, and it seems there is no support for APC on PHP 5.5, I read that PHP5.5 have OpCache out of the box, but is it an alternative for APC? If yes How can I configure a Cache Storage Adapter for OpCache? if it is not to replace APC what can I use for PHP5.5? and how to configure an Adapter for it.

Comment: you can use APCu - https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu

Comment: The problem with APCu is that there is no Cache Adapter for it in Zend Framework 2

Comment: why should it need a cache adapter, and presents itself (by default) as APC, it has the API of APC ... no need for adaptation is there !?

Comment: I meant by Cache Adapter a Class from ZF2 that wrap the API, and to use APCu without writing my own Adapter class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the APCu like @ziollek's said. Starting from Php 5.5 Apc removed in favor of Opcache but [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu) is a drop-in replacement for APC and it runs fully compatible with the good old APC.

So, Zend's [APC cache storage adapter](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Cache/Storage/Adapter/Apc.php) should work with APCu too.

See: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/7

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK OpCache differs from APC in that it's purely for caching scripts. You might want to take a look at the zf2 [memcache adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-memcached-adapter) or hand roll your own with [redis](http://redis.io/) by implementing this [interface](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Cache/Storage/StorageInterface.php). There are instructions [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-storageinterface) for implementing the interface, so it shouldn't be hard.

I use both memcache and redis extensively. I find memcache simpler but redis to have more functionality. If you only need a key-value store, i'd go with memcache as the adapter is pre-written.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I ended up using xcache for caching user data, since other caches like memcached have some issues with cross platforms availability (yes, I mean windows...!)